# PHP Select Option MYSQL

Tags: php

Tenho uma pagina onde a pessoa Adiciona valores da Database.

```
<?php   
    $get = ("SELECT movie_id, movie_name FROM movies ORDER BY movie_name DESC");
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $get);

    $option = '';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    { 
      $option .= "<option value = '".$row['movie_id']."'>".$row['movie_name']."</option>";
    }
?>           

<form action="includes/reload.php" method='POST'>
    <select name="selectionD" id="fname">         
        <?php
            echo "<option value='0'>Escolha a Serie...</option>";
            echo "<option value='0'></option>";
            echo $option;
        ?>        
    </select>          

   <input type="text" class='' id="fname" name="sess" maxlength='3' placeholder="Nº Temporada" required>
   <input type="hidden" value='' name="movid"  hidden>
   <input type="text" id="fname" name="episode" maxlength='3' placeholder="Nº Episódio" required>

    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" name='saveNew'>
</form>
```

O resultado disso é adicionar registos na Database com os valores $movie_id, sessao e episodio...

Mas eu queria tambem adicionar o nome do Episodio, como veem na <.Option.> Name <.Option.>.. $row['movie_name']... Apenas consigo polo como texto...

Existe alguma forma de adicionar tambem o nome do filme juntamente com a opção escolhida na OPTION?

Exemplo.. Se eu escolher Opçao 1, ele dame o Value pretendido da DB, mas nao conigo fazer com que guarde tambem o NOME.

Comment: Quanto ao código sem dificuldades, a dificuldade é entender o que vc quer com esse "guarde tambem o NOME"